# CSS class with space before

Tags: css

How can I target an element class with a space before? I am using a Slick carousel slider and it automatically drops in a space in one of my elements I have within.

Example:

```
<div class=" classwithspace">Read more</div>
```

Is this still read as

> .classwithspace{color:red;}

Comment: > Is this still read as `.classwithspace` - yes. Check whether or not your styles are applied in the Developer Tools; if latter, it'll show you the overrides.

Comment: @ManojKumar Actually it doesn't **ignore** the spaces. The browser uses the spaces as separators instead of class parts.

Comment: The value of `class` attribute is a space-separated list of classes. That means the space can't be part of any class

Comment: @sailens My bad! That is the use case for multiple classes. With respect to OP's code, the space will be ignored if it contains only a single class.

Comment: Works fine without any special handling here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/LpmEjL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking from the comment of [sailens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3690438/sailens)

> The space will be not be part of class name, the browser uses the
>   spaces as separators instead of class parts.

```css
.classwithspace{
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class=" classwithspace">Read more</div>
```

Comment: I commented the same "The space will be ignored."  on the question before I had to see another use case. I think it is worth mentioning sailens' comment in the question. Space is ignored only if there is a single class. Otherwise it is treated as a separator.

Comment: I was just talking about the question's context, Wanted to try before I post the answer. but yes i will add the point mentioned.